# Background service for polling aws sqs as part of an ASP.NET Core application (AWS ECS)

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, background-service

I have an ASP.NET Core application that is deployed with ECS and includes some controllers.

For now there are two consumers:

1. Another ASP.NET Core MVC application that make http requests
2. Client application (Angular)

Now I need a service that will receive messages from SNS but will use the same ASP.NET Core application dependencies like database, services, dtos etc.

I have two options

1. Create new SQS that will be subscribe to the SNS and new Lambda that will do what is needed when messages received by making http requests to the ASP.NET Core application (third consumer)
2. Create a new Background service as part of the services layer of the ASP.NET Core application that will poll SQS in order to get messages
   (I am not sure how background service will effect the performances)

What is the best approach (does not have to be from the list above) take into consideration best architecture practice and performance aspect?

Thank you

Comment: Background service works great for this. One tidbit, if you use short polling it may talk a few cycles to pick up new messages in the queue. Long poling with a 30 second time out works good. Also, setting the message visibility timeout is helpful or you could process the same message multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What about perfomances? Background service with while loop, can it effect on other consumers of the web api?

Comment: That depends on the scale of incoming requests. If done correctly, async and non-blocking then it should be fine. You are going to have to poll one way either by looping or using a timer. If performance is life/death mission then you could always break it out into a windows service application or exe to remove the entire IIS pipeline overhead. If your aim is to go more serverless then Lambda would be the correct path.

Comment: Thank you I will start with the background service